# Vim to highlight only a submatch

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

Folks, I'm writing a syntax highlighting script for vim, but I'm struggling on how to highlight only a submatch of a pattern.

For example, suppose that I want to highlight any number within `#`, like `#42#` to highlight **only** the 42 and not the `#`.

I don't fully understand what the [\@=](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C@=) operator does, but I'm trying to use it like so:

```
syn match Number "\(#\)\@=\d\+\(#\)\@="
```

**Edit:**
Just complementing Kent's answer, from the man page:

```
                            */\zs*
\zs Matches at any position, and sets the start of the match there: The
    next char is the first char of the whole match. |/zero-width|
    Example: >
        /^\s*\zsif
<   matches an "if" at the start of a line, ignoring white space.
    Can be used multiple times, the last one encountered in a matching
    branch is used.  Example: >
        /\(.\{-}\zsFab\)\{3}
<   Finds the third occurrence of "Fab".
    {not in Vi} {not available when compiled without the |+syntax| feature}
                            */\ze*
\ze Matches at any position, and sets the end of the match there: The
    previous char is the last char of the whole match. |/zero-width|
    Can be used multiple times, the last one encountered in a matching
    branch is used.
    Example: "end\ze\(if\|for\)" matches the "end" in "endif" and
    "endfor".
    {not in Vi} {not available when compiled without the |+syntax| feature}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\zs` and `\ze`:

```
syn match Number "#\zs\d\+\ze#"
```

Comment: In my original problem I have to match more than a single number in the same line, and I just found out that `"#\zs\d\+\ze#\zs\d\+\ze#"` won't work. Do you know how to make multiple matches in the same line, or I should make another question?

Comment: Are all the matches part of the same match? (I.e. between the same set of `#` separators?) If yes, what separates the numbers? Rewrite the rule taking into account the possible sub-separators. If not, things should *already* work as is.

Comment: I realized that my doubt is a whole new question, so I made one [here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/syntax-highlight-multiple-matches-in-the-same-line).

Comment: @Kira Vanlaser is right. keep in mind that `#123#456#` is `#123#` and `#456#` so the same cmd should work too.

Comment: The problem is that this is not my actual problem, I've used a fictional example just for simplicity, check this [question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/syntax-highlight-multiple-matches-in-the-same-line) for something more specific.