# Syntax highlight multiple matches in the same line

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression

I would like to know how to highlight multiple tokens in the same line.

For example, if I want to highlight the value of 'a', I can write something like this:

```
syn match num  'a=\zs\d\+\ze,b=\d\+.*'
```

This would highlight the number 42 in `a=42,b=5`.

Now what if I want to highlight both numbers? I know that something like `'a=\zs\d\+\ze,b=\zs\d\+\ze.*'` won't work because it only highlights the last number.

Please note that I **don't** want to highlight all the numbers in the line, so if I have a string like `(a=1,b=2,c=3)`, I only want to highlight `1` and `2` (i.e. the values of `a` and `b`).

**Edit:** Also note that `a` and `b` should be adjacent, with `b` following `a`. So `(a=1,b=2,b=3)` should highlight only `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 2):

Given that:

> so if I have a string like z=5,a=1,b=2,c=3, I only want to highlight 1
>   and 2 (i.e. the values of a and b).

This works:

```
syn match Number "[ab]=\zs\d\+"
```

Or this:

```
syn match Number "\(^\|[\s,]\)[ab]=\zs\d\+"
```

The below one won't match variables like `faaa=..` or `xxxb=`

Comment: I did not make myself clear enough, please check the edited question.

Comment: @Kira It is long time I haven't written syntax file. I have to test with your example. however I don't get time right now. But I think you need to use the `contains, contained and nextgroup`  check `:h syn-nextgroup` for detail, there is an example.